# How to get specific date?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have to show date on my jsp that date will be the up coming wednesday date of week.For example if today is "friday 3 june 2012" and customer get login today then i have to show him mgs that Your order will be deliver on Wednesday "date". that "date" will be the live date of coming wednesday meanse Wednesday 8 june 2012. 
how i get my requirement using Jquery .

Comment: show us what you have tried? Also tell us where you are facing problem...

Answer (score 4):

With this you are able to get the weekday of today:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
```

A 3 means Wednesday so create a loop:

```
var d = new Date();
while (d.getDay() != 3) {
    d = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()+1);
}
```

**Update**

Working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mavrick3/3UEAZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

you have to do calculation on current date

```
var currentTime = new Date()
```

just find out the days to add in current date and do processing according your need.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <h4>It is now  
   <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
     var currentTime = new Date()
      var hours = currentTime.getHours()
         var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
           if (minutes < 10){
           minutes = "0" + minutes
                  }
             document.write(hours + ":" + minutes + " ")
           f(hours > 11){
               document.write("PM")
                 } else {
           document.write("AM")
            }
               //-->
            </script>
               </h4>
```

Macci Refer this

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following:

```
var DateCalc = (function () {
    var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
        months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
        getNextWed = function () {
            var d = new Date();
            while (d.getDay() != 3) {
                d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
            }
            return d;
        },
        formatDate = function (d) {
            var str = [];

            str.push(days[d.getDay(days)]);
            str.push(d.getDate());    
            str.push(months[d.getMonth()]);
            str.push(d.getFullYear());

            return str.join(' ');
        };           
    return {
        getNextWedStr: function () {
            return formatDate(getNextWed());
        }
    };
})();

console.log(DateCalc.getNextWedStr()); // "Wednesday 27 June 2012 "
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/9hqLE/).

This will match the current day if it's a Wednesday. If it always has to be the **next** Wednesday then just do:

```
...
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1); // <-- this
while (d.getDay() != 3) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Java** in JSP page, you can do it in below way.

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

/**
*
* @author fahim
*/
public class DateExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

        System.out.println("" + cal.getTime());
        int i = cal.get(7);
        if (i == 1) { // sunday
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 3);
        } else if (i == 2) { // monday
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2);
        } else if (i == 3) { // tuesdat
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
        } else if (i == 4) { // wednesday
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7);
        } else if (i == 5) { // hursday
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);
        } else if (i == 6) { // friday
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 5);
        } else if (i == 7) { // saturday
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 4);
        }        

        System.out.println("" + cal.getTime());
    }
}
```

Output I get as

```
Wed Jun 27 15:39:44 AST 2012
Wed Jul 04 15:39:44 AST 2012
```

### [Demo at www.ideone.com](http://ideone.com/XZWfQ)